# Trouble extracting zip in python over ftp

Tags: python, subprocess, 7zip, zip, os.system

I'm trying to unzip a file from an FTP site.  I've tried it using 7z in a subprocess as well as using 7z in the older os.system format.  I get closest however when I'm using the zipfile module in python so I've decided to stick with that.  No matter how I edit this I seem to get one of two errors so here are both of them so y'all can see where I'm banging my head against the wall:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(r"\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\daily\data1.zip" % item)
z.extractall()
```

NotImplementedError: compression type 6 (implode)
(I think this one is totally wrong, but figured I'd include.)

I seem to get the closest with the following:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(r"\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\daily\data1.zip" % item)
z.extractall(r"\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\daily\data1.zip" % item)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\svr-dc...'
```

The catch with this is that it is actually giving me the first file name in the zip.  I can see the file AJ07242013.PRN at the end of the error so I feel closer because it's at least getting to the point of reading the contents of the zip file.

Pretty much any iteration of this that I try gets me one of those two errors, or a syntax error but that's easily addressed and not my primary concern.

Sorry for being so long winded.  I'd love to get this working, so let me know what you think I need to do.

EDIT:

So 7z has finally been added to the path and is running through without any errors with both the subprocess as well as os.system.  However, I still can't seem to get anything to unpack.  It looks to me, from all I've read in the python documentation that I should be using the subprocess.communicate() module to extract this file but it just won't unpack.  When I use os.system it keeps telling me that it cannot find the archive.

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['7z', 'e']
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

sp.communicate('r"\C:\Users\boster\Desktop\Data1.zip"')
```

I don't think that sp.communicate is right but if I add anything else to it I have too many arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work without using the PIPE functionality as subprocess.communicate wouldn't unpack the files.  Here was the solution using subprocess.call.  Hope this can help someone in the future.

```
def extract_data_one():
    for item in sites:
        os.chdir(r"\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\Daily" % item)
    subprocess.call(['7z', 'e', 'data1.zip', '*.*'])
```

Answer (score 1):

python's zipfile doesn't support compression type 6 (imploded) so its simply not going to work. In the first case, that's obvious from the error. In the second case, things are worse. The parameter for extractfile is an alternate unzip directory. Since you gave it the name of your zip file, a directory of the same name can't be found and zipfile gives up before getting to the not-supported problem.

Make sure you can do this with 7z on the command line, try implementing subprocess again and ask for help on that technique if you need it.

Here's a script that will look for 7z in the usual places:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from glob import glob

print 'python version:', sys.version
subprocess.call('ver', shell=True)
print

if os.path.exists(r'C:\Program Files\7-Zip'):
    print 'have standard 7z install'
    if '7-zip' in os.environ['PATH'].lower():
        print '...and its in the path'
    else:
        print '...but its not in the path'
    print

print 'find in path...'
found = 0
for p in os.environ['PATH'].split(os.path.pathsep):
    candidate = os.path.join(p, '7z.*')
    for fn in glob(candidate):
        print '    found', fn
        found += 1
print

if found:
    print '7z located, attempt run'
    subprocess.call(['7z'])
else:
    print '7z not found'
```

Comment: So it appears that I am getting a "cannot find the file expected" error on the import from subprocess.  I don't get past the third line of this code before it fails.                                              'import subprocess
cmd = ['7z', 'e', 'Test.7z', 'Test', '-mx9']
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)'                                             It seems to be failing on that third line and not even getting into the function.  Thoughts?

Comment: And I know that the actual '7z e' works because it will unpack the items in the command line outside of python.

Comment: It should work... if that's any consolation! Is it a python exception stack ending in "The system cannot find the file expected"? That means that it couldn't find 7z. Is it properly installed? Try a couple of tests in the interactive python shell from the same place you run your regular script, like `subprocess.call(['7z'])` (it should print 7z help) and `os.isfile('Test.7z')` (it should be True). You don't need the -mx9 on the end, but I think that's mostly harmless.

Comment: Okay, 7z is valid and I can bring up the help on a simple command line but it doesn't work at all in Python.  I've reinstalled python and 7zip and even installed PyLZMA and still have no luck with this.  Any ideas?

Comment: it works for me (smile). Its all shots in the dark at this point, but bring up a new command prompt to make sure you have the latest environment, type `where 7z`, then go to python and see if that path is in os.environ['PATH'].

Comment: So it does appear to be there.  It doesn't follow it all the way to the 7z.exe like it does outside of python but it's path "C:/Windows/System32" is there.  This is driving me crazy.  This is the most important part of the app and it's the only part that's not working.

Comment: Alright, so I've gone into my environment variables and added the python folder so that I can run python from anywhere and I've got new errors.  Trying the subprocess.call gets me a 'function object has no attribute 'get item'.'

Comment: Did you type `subprocess.call['7z']`? It should be `subprocess.call(['7z'])` - you need the parens. So, 7z.exe is in C:/Windows/System32? Try `subprocess.call([r'C:\Windows\System32\7z.exe'])`.

Comment: I definitely used the parens.  It isn't working still on either simply 7z or including the directory with the r to include the first character.

Comment: I just posted a script that tries to find 7z. Other than that... I'm at a loss.

Comment: Well I can't say that you didn't try.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: It took me two days of playing but I eventually found 7z out of path.  I just created a .pth for in my Python27 folder and it's working now.  Your script was a life saver.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to the ZipFile documentation, you might be better off copying the zip first to your working directory. (http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.extract)

If you have problems copying, you might want to store the zip in a path with no spaces or protect your code against spaces by using os.path.

I made a small test in which I used os.path.abspath to make sure I had the proper path to my zip and it worked properly.
Also make sure that for extractall the path that you specify is the path where the zip content will be extracted. (If a folder that is specified is not created, it will be created automatically) Your files will be extracted in your current working directory (CWD) if no parameter is passed to extractall.

Cheers!